# Optimizing filters

Tags: ssas, powerbi, tabular

I have a doubt on performance optimization on a very large model. I modelled a standard star-schema for a fact table of roughly 600M rows.
I use this model to serve a PowerBI report. Almost every report object is filtered on a fact table's column. I was told that by creating a `dimension` made of only that column and by filtering on it while linking it to the fact table it'll increase performance, but I'm skeptical. 
The column in question has very few unique values.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Wheter or not is a good strategy adding a dimension or it's better to filter directly on the fact table